Can plasmas have eddy currents?
A couple days ago I asked a question on if plasma could have a magnetic field due to current which was a yes. Now I am wondering again on if plasma can possess eddy currents. Assuming a time varying magnetic field near 1 tesla would hot plasma (6000 degrees Celsius) have eddy currents and levitate the magnet?

Also I kinda suck at physics so I might not have specified some units or what not.

It’s also pretty late at night so my grammar might be off

A plasma is generally going to be too light to levitate any magnet but yes it definitely will have eddy currents. Unavoidable, really.

Yes, plasmas can exhibit things akin to an eddy current, but probably not in the sense you might be thinking.  There are phenomena that behave diamagnetically but I cannot think of any paramagnetic phenomena (doesn't mean there isn't any, I just cannot think of any off the top of my head).  Also, a 2000 degree kelvin (~0.17 eV) plasma would be an extremely cold plasma.  Most plasmas (by volume) in the universe are closer to 1 eV... Well never mind, I suppose the ISM is likely around 0.1 eV so okay this is fine.  The solar wind, for comparison, is ~5-10 eV.

Yes. Induced currents in plasmas can be useful. The poloidal field in a tokamak is an eddy current induced by a magnetic field that threads the torus.
